# Query was already executed: User.find({}), why iam getting this error?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

**

```js
filtersRouter.js:-
filtersRouter.get('/search', getEmployeesByKey)


filterController.js
//?find employees by search key
export const getEmployeesByKey = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
  const filters = req.query;
  // filters.clone();
  // const expr= req.query. expr;
  // const {location, role} = req.query
  const filterdusers = await User.find(user =>{
    let isValid = true;
    for(let key in filters){
      console.log(key, user[key], filters[key]);
      isValid = isValid && user[key] == filters[key]
    }
    return isValid;
  });
  if (!employees) {
    return res_failed(res, "Employees are not found");
  }
  res_success(res, "search done", filterdusers);
  console.log(res.query);
  res.status(200).json(
    {filterdusers}
  )

  }catch(error){
    res_catch(res, error);
  }
};
```

**search the employees by giving the values dynamically like "location":"hyderabad", "skills":"nodeJS" like this.

if i give the values like "location: Hyderabd", "skills:nodeJS", it should have to print the details of employees according to given input.

Comment: Try with `const filterdusers = await User.find(filters);`